# how to change newsletter footer text?

Tags: magento-1.7, newsletter, footer

Which file do I have to edit to change the description text for the newsletter subscription box?

[image: newsletter footer text change magento]

Comment: hello please accept the answer if it helped you. Please dont leave a question as it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little short on context, but in a standard Magento installation, the newsletter `phtml` template is located at

```
app/design/base/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml
```

which means it will be located at

```
app/design/[PACKAGE-NAME]/[THEME-NAME]/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml
```

if your theme conforms to the Magento standard. For example, the `modern` and `default` theme (part of the `default` design package) have the following files.

```
app/design/default/iphone/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml
app/design/default/modern/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml
```

However, your screen shot indicates you're using a custom theme, which means all bets are off.